# Is it advisable to call java dao class method from a jsp page

Tags: java, database, jsp, servlets

I want the user to see his/her own details  after clicking the view button.So in a jsp page i have created a link like this

```html
<a href="viewuser.jsp">View</a>
```

I have set the empid as session attribute earlier while authenticating but now as i am redirecting the user to the following link where i have to show his/her details only.

My doubt is we can obviously call the dao class method to fetch the user's data ,from the jsp page but is it a good programming practice or i have to call the servlet first then jsp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **must not** have any scriptlet/direct Java code in your JSP. Please **avoid its usage**. More info on this: [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197) (no need to explain one more time all the problems you get when using scriptlets).

You should use a Servlet that will handle the GET request for your JSP and the Servlet (Controller) will be the link between your View and your Model (Service, Dao, etc). This is a very basic example:

```
@WebServlet("/viewuser.jsp")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        int empid = (Integer)request.getSession().getAttribute("empid");
        //assuming EmployeeService is a service class that has a getEmployee method
        //that will handle the work to a dao to retrieve data from database 
        //or another data source and will return an Employee object
        Employee employee = new EmployeeService().getEmployee(empid);
        request.setAttribute("employee", employee);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/viewuser.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

And then in your viewuser.jsp file (shortened code):

```html
<p>
    Name: <c:out value="${employee.name}" />
</p>
```

Comment: How i will create a link to servlet using a tag?

Comment: The servlet will habdle a url. The link just has to point to such url.

Comment: You mean using  <a href="/servletmappingurl" >view</a> ,after clicking view servlet will be invoked .Am i right ? And then it will take care of the rest.

Comment: @Mayank note that in my example, the base URL is *viewuser.jsp*. Yes, you can even map your servlet to a HTML or a JSP file.

Comment: thanks ,i just tried to map servlet ,it invoked the get method but i want to invoke the post method. :(

Comment: @Mayank that's because you're performing a GET request. Every access from a browser over a direct URL is done through GET request. You can perform POST requests using a `<form action="POST">`.

Comment: Thanks sir ,i got all my answers